# Laravel Eloquent search by Date Range

Tags: mysql, laravel, date, search, eloquent

I have two table "patient" and "booking" table, and there is a relationship "One to Many" between them, I made a search form in an index_booking page where a user can type a patient_name on it to search by user name according to WHERE Condition also search by date range , but there is no data appear in form till i search by date , so i don't know why the data dose not  show by default according the WHERE condition :

This is Booking Model

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

    public function patient()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

This is Patient Model

```
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
    public function booking()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

And i used this code in index page of booking

```
   <div class="search1">
           {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url'=>'booking','class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left','role'=>'search'])  !!}
           <!--<span class="badge">{{$bookings->count()}}</span>-->

       </div>
  <tr>

   <div class="col col-md-3">
     <p></span><input type="text" id="end" name="end" placeholder="الي تاريخ"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></p> 
   </div>

   <div class="col col-md-4">
     <p><input type="text" id="start" name="start" placeholder="من تاريخ"></p> 
   </div>
    <td class="title search col-md-5">
    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="ابحث بالاسم...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default-sm" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"> <span class="hiddenGrammarError" pre="" data-mce-bogus="1"></span></i>
        </button>
    </span>

</div>
    </td>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

i used this code in Booking Controller to show data according to Where 
 condition and search by date range:

```
       public function index(Request $request)
    {


$search = Request::get('search');
$start = Request::input('start');
$end = Request::input('end');

$bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search, $start, $end) {
$query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
      ->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(booking_date)'), [$start, $end]) ;


})->where('status','=', null)->whereHas('patient', function ($query){
  $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id); 

})->orderBy("id", "asc") 
  ->paginate(7);
  return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);


}


    }
```

Javascript code in booking index is:

```
 <script>
          $(function(){$("#start").datepicker({
            autoclose:!0,
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
            startDate:new Date
        }),
        $("#end").datepicker({
            autoclose:!0,
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
            endDate:new Date
        })
    });
```

Comment: maybe just add a condition if you want to add the date filter. `if($start && $end) { $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('date(booking_date)'), [$start, $end]) ; }

Comment: try `whereBetween('booking_date', [$start, $end])` instead and check the result.

Comment: @ elegisandi , where to add this condition it will make a syntax error

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd   no change in this solution : whereBetween('booking_date', [$start, $end])